# How do I put a parameter that is a string into a path for a URL?

Tags: swift, url, avplayer, filepath

Here is what I tried and I get this error:

> No exact matches in call to initializer

```
struct VideoBox: View {
    var videoname : String
    var ext : String
    var filepath1 : String
    var filepath2 : String
    var fullfilepath : String
    
    init(videoname: String) {
        self.videoname = videoname
        ext = "mp4"
        
        filepath1 = "fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "
        filepath2 = ", ofType: \"\(ext)\")!)"
        fullfilepath = "\(filepath1) \"\(self.videoname)\" \(filepath2)"
      }
    
    
   @State var player = AVPlayer (url: URL(fullfilepath))
```

My call to `VideoBox` is this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
     
    let videoname = "3mintestvideo"
    var body: some View {
        VideoBox (videoname: videoname)
    }
}
```

The `fullfilepath` value prints out as:

```
fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "3mintestvideo, ofType: "mp4")!)
```

Comment: Why not use `Bundle.main.url(forResource:withExtension)` which returns a `URL`?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're trying to include code within a `String` when you do `"fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "`. Instead, you should use the actual `Bundle.main` code (outside of a String). You can also get a `URL` directly from the bundle -- you don't need to convert between a path and URL.

```
struct SampleView : View {
    @State var player : AVPlayer
    
    init(videoname: String) {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: videoname, withExtension: "mp4") {
            _player = State(initialValue: AVPlayer(url: url))
        } else {
            _player = State(initialValue: AVPlayer())
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("test")
    }
}
```

Note that doing too much in a `View`'s `init` can be dangerous -- if this `View` gets loaded multiple times, you may want to consider moving the player to a view model that only calls the loading code *once* in `onAppear`:

```
struct SampleView : View {
    var videoname : String
    @StateObject private var sampleViewModel : SampleViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("test").onAppear {
            sampleViewModel.loadVideo(videoname: videoname)
        }
        if let player = sampleViewModel.player {
            //use the player here
        }
    }
}

class SampleViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var player : AVPlayer?
    
    func loadVideo(videoname : String) {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: videoname, withExtension: "mp4") {
            player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        } else {
            player = AVPlayer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is very clear. I will give it a try

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, you can mark it as accepted with the green checkmark.